# PHP Session should not expire even if user close the tab till user clicks on logout

Tags: php, session

I have logout page when i click on logout or close the tab, session gets destroy. I want if user forgot to click on logout and if user visit the site after 4-5 days still the session should continue.

I have following logout script:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);
unset($_SESSION['uid']);
unset($_SESSION['uname']);

session_destroy();

header("location:http://shopeeon.com/");
?>
```

Comment: for more sure you can also add $_SESSION = [];

Comment: sessions are destroyed as per `session.gc_maxlifetime` and `session.cookie_lifetime` as well as maybe a few others within php.ini or `ini_set`.   [you can read some of the comments on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25485077/is-it-possible-to-set-unlimited-session-timeout-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change value of your session timeout in PHP configuration file. Don't forget to restart Apache.
[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8311400/2059056)
.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your user to be logged back in after closing a browser (and the session dying), then you need to use a cookie to identify the user securely.

Search on here for some similar questions; examples

- [What is the correct and safe/secure way to keep a user logged in? cookies? session? PHP && MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566988/what-is-the-correct-and-safe-secure-way-to-keep-a-user-logged-in-cookies-sessi)
- [PHP Cookie to keep user logged in - is this secure enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447409/php-cookie-to-keep-user-logged-in-is-this-secure-enough)

Answer (score 0):

I have used this htaccess in  root :

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    #Session timeout
    php_value session.cookie_lifetime 31536000
    php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 31536000
</IfModule>
```

Comment: do i have to make this changes in php.ini file

Comment: @RashmiSonke. If you use .htaccess file  in root folder with above code  then you do not need to modify php.ini file.

Comment: i m on shared host and .htaccess file is not editable

Comment: @RashmiSonke. ok. now you have to modify php.ini file. 
If you do not have access to this file, create a new file inside root folder 'php.ini' and paste this code  
session.gc_maxlifetime = 48000
session.cookie_lifetime = 48000

Comment: If the user revisits the site after 4/5 days, the session will have been destroyed. I do not see this solution working for a revisit; therefore you need the help of cookies as per my answer.